# Unexpected token ILLEGAL from template toolkit with Javascript,

Tags: javascript, bugzilla, template-toolkit

```
var x = document.getElementById('comments');
x.innerHTML=  '[% PROCESS bug/comments.html.tmpl'+
            ' comments = bug.comments,'+
            ' mode = "edit" %] ';
```

I don't see any type of invalid characters, I have also tried to put double slash (//). what I am missing?

Comment: the provided code is not cause of your ILLEGAL error - check code before/after this one or use a good error console (like the one in Chrome or Firebug for Firefox)

Comment: What is throwing the error, that template toolkit?

Comment: @ZathrusWriter you right, inside the process i have script tag, thanks.
Bergi chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code have to be something like this

```
var x = document.getElementById('comments');
x.innerHTML=  '[%~ PROCESS bug/comments.html.tmpl comments = bug.comments, mode = "edit" ~%]';
```